# Using Audio Unit (Mixer Host) to play from iPod library instead of pre selected sound files.

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipod, mixing

For a university project i'm working on a DJ mixing app. I'm essentially tackling this project from a 'teach yourself from scratch by googling everything and analysing pre existing source code' type of way so go easy.

I have looked at the Mixer Host sample project from apple found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010210

I can't work out how to replace the pre selected audio files (guitar + beat) with a song URL from the iPod library selected from a media picker, or, in this case - 2 media pickers.

Is it a case of grabbing the URL of the iPod library song selected and putting in place of the URL of the preselected audio file?

If someone could point me in the right direction, tell me how i'm completely going about this the wrong way, or even do the coding for me (joke), it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually simply stream from the ipod library; you need to copy the files into the documents directory of the app.

try this: http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party libraries to play a iPod library songs using AudioUnit. The below link is useful to you

Click[here](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html)!